# Unable to identify and click on the "Next" button in date field

Tags: java, selenium, date

I am trying to automate the flight booking of http://www.mercurytravels.co.in using Selenium+java.
The issue that I am facing is that I'm unable to click on the ">" (next button) of the "Date of Return" date field in the Book Flights Online page.

Getting error message that --> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

The code that I've written is:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='returnDate']")).click();
    
    //Retrieving current year value
    String currentReturnMonthYear = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]")).click();
```

Request any inputs on issue that I'm facing?

Comment: You could try to use a `Wait` that explicitly waits until `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(WebElement element)`... Have you tried to `Wait` already?

Comment: Tried using wait and ExpectedConditions but getting timeout exception. Code that I updated was:    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]"))));
  
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]")).click();

Comment: Have you tried a `Wait<WebDriver> wait = FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)...` instead? You can apply a polling interval and some timeout.

Comment: Getting similar timeOut exception on using FluentWait

Comment: OK, then it's some different issue. Looks like you are trying to select an item of a dropdown menu, which you could alternatively try to get using a `Select`. Have you tried that so far?

Comment: Its not the dropdown menu but rather the date field. I'm trying to select the date in the "Date of Return" field of the "Flights" page. For that, I'm looking to navigate to a particular month (e.g. December 2021, January 2022 etc) by clicking on the ">" button within the date field.

Comment: Could you post the particular html/css snippet and maybe an image of how it looks rendered?

Comment: You can find the html code within the flight booking section of the http://www.mercurytravels.co.in website. Sharing across the snippet as requested::::<div class="datepicker dropdown-menu" style="display: block; top: 393.05px; left: 357.767px;">
 <div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">
  <table class=" table-condensed">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="prev">‹</th>
     <th colspan="5" class="switch">November 2021</th>
     <th class="next">›</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

Answer (score 0):

`org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException` Indicates that a click could not be properly executed because the target element was obscured in some way. ElementNotInteractableException is Thrown to indicate that although an element is present on the DOM, it is not in a state that can be interacted with.

**Using `Explicit` wait**:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='returnDate']")).click();
    WebElement next = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
            "//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]")));
    next.click();
```

**Using `Actions`**:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='returnDate']")).click();
    WebElement next = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
            "//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]")));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(next).click().build().perform();
```

**Using `JavascriptExecutor`**:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='returnDate']")).click();
    WebElement next = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(
            "//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]")));
    JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    javascriptExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", next);
```

Comment: I tried all the above 3 options and its failing (for me) for all the options. Same error is displayed :( . Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Instead of `elementToBeClickable` please try `visibilityOfElement` or `presenceOfElement` and check again.

Comment: Is there a better way I could capture the path of the ">" (next) button of the date of return date field? I am using the xpath --> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='datepicker dropdown-menu'][4]/div[@class='datepicker-days']/table[@class=' table-condensed']/thead/tr[1]/th[3]"))

Comment: Yes. Please try `(//div[@class='datepicker-days']//th[@class='next' and text()='›'])[4]`

Comment: Have you tried by changing visibility or presence?

Comment: Is that working?

Comment: Will be trying it today and would get back. Thanks for the inputs